# Convert Perl library to SOAP

Tags: perl, soap

I have a Perl library and want to use SOAP to do the following:

- Expose a list of all functions in the library, including the 
  signature of each function and the perldoc (human-readable 
  description of the function and its parameters).
- Allow people to call a given function and receive an answer in a 
  SOAP-standard way.

I could try doing this by hand, but what tools will convert a Perl 
library to a SOAP server "automatically"?

In particular, I don't want to write the WSDL and stuff like that by hand.

My goal here: provide a minimal "zero cosmetics" interface to my 
functions, and let other people create HTTP form/Javascript/etc 
interfaces to my functions.

More detail added later:

To break it down a bit, I need these things:

% Something to convert my Perl functions' signatures to a WSDL 
 file. Ultimately, I want the WSDL URL to be the only thing people 
 need to access my SOAP service.

% Something that converts an incoming SOAP request to a function call.

% Something that converts the results of a function call to the 
 SOAP-like XML the client expects.

This can't be that difficult, can it?

Answer (score 3):

If your library uses `Moose`, try [WSDL::Compile](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WSDL%3a%3aCompile).

You can convert arbitrary structures with [WSDL::Generator::Schema](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WSDL%3a%3aGenerator%3a%3aSchema) and [WSDL::Generator](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WSDL%3a%3aGenerator).

You can generate Perl interface classes from the WSDL above with [SOAP::WSDL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP%3a%3aWSDL).

Comment: OK, I don't know what Moose is. This is a simple Perl library, something like https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bclib.pl although that's not a great example since many functions only work locally. But the general idea is that I have simple Perl functions in a library. Basically, is there a server/software that does the whole thing for me w/o my having to code the SOAP wrapper on the existing library?

Comment: @barrycarter, I don't think it's worth exposing a web service for those functions. Every one of them is far better handled by more robust modules, many of which are in the Perl core. And you sure as hell don't want random HTTP clients calling your `dodie` sub.

Comment: @friedo Apologies. That was just a library I happened to have online. The "real" library I want to convert (not online yet) will be much more complex, access external data sources, etc. Think of this as a sample library: if I can do it with library (for, say, just max and min), then I can do it w/ the library I actually want to convert.

To say it even more directly: I like writing functions. I dislike writing interfaces. Help me, Obi-wan!

Comment: The real library has a limited set of functions written carefully with the foreknowledge that the parameters are coming from an untrusted source. Once the parameters reach the functions, it's the functions' responsibility to keep things safe. However, if the SOAP wrapper gets a parameter like \`rm -rf /\`, it shouldn't execute that code, just send it as a parameter to the correct function.